Fundamentals of pricing theory, Arrow security pricing
I aim to make the derivative's pricing theory abloslutely clear for myself, starting from the beginnigs. Before turning to risk-neutral measure and Radon-Nikodym change-of-measure, I'd like to price an Arrow security.
Suppose there is some market event $A_T$, and we bet on it: someone suggests us to pay one unit, if $A_T$ would be the case at the future time moment $T$ (e.g., some stock hits the barrier, or someone defaults etc). So, $X_T=\mathbb{I}_{A_T}$. What is the price $X_t$, at $t<T$?
Financial economics texts say that (given some probabilistic model) $X_t=\mathbb{E}[\tilde{m}_tX_T]=\mathbb{E}[\tilde{m}_t\mathbb{I}_A]$, where $\tilde{m}_t$ is a stochastic discount factor.
Why expectation? Let us even simplify it to $X_T=1$, the case of a zero-coupon bond. Why its price should be the expectation $\mathbb{E}[\tilde{m}_t]$ of something? I can even reduce it to a single-step binomial model, but cannot easily accept the expectation, which is the weighted sum.
So, why expectation is the price? And what is the price, finally?

Roughly speaking, because of the Von Neumann–Morgenstern utility theorem:

the VNM utility theorem demonstrates that rational choice under uncertainty involves making decisions that take the form of maximizing the expected value of some cardinal utility function.

